# how to validate comment-size text from the text inserted in the comment box using Cypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress, ui-automation, cypress-custom-commands

hi folks as I am new to this automation/cypress world i need your help to handle this problem statement

i have a comment box something similar to this i am able to put text inside this text with

```
cy.get('#comments').type('TEST')
```

but there is a element similar to this which shows character count as

```
*4/4000 Characters Used
```

instead of highlighted one

what i wanted ?
i wanted to validate the text with the on run time

what i have done so far

i have created a `custom command` which return the text out of element by passing its locator

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getElementText', (locator) => {
  cy.get(locator).invoke('text').then((text)=>{
  return text.length
})
})
```

what i needed

```
cy.get('#commentSize').invoke('text').should('eq','*'+cy.getElementText('#comments').then((text)=>{return text})+'/4000 Characters Used')
```

so that the final validation should appear like this

```
cy.get('#commentSize').invoke('text').should('eq','*'+ '4' +'/4000 Characters Used')
```

but i am getting assert error `expected 4 to equal * [object Object]NaN`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap and then return your text like this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getElementText', (locator) => {
  cy.get(locator)
    .invoke('text')
    .then((text) => {
      return cy.wrap(text.length)
    })
})
```

Then in your test you have to do this:

```js
cy.getElementText('#comments').then((len) => {
  cy.get('#commentSize')
    .invoke('text')
    .should('eq', '*' + len + '/4000 Characters Used')
})
```

You can also directly assert using the `should('have.text')`like this:

```js
cy.getElementText('#comments').then((len) => {
  cy.get('#commentSize').should(
    'have.text',
    '*' + len + '/4000 Characters Used'
  )
})
```

Comment: thanks @Alapan Das this solution works but is their any better way of performing this validation

Comment: I think this is a good way. I would suggest changing the name from `getElementText ` to `getElementTextLength`. Also if you are extracting and using the length just once, don't use cypress command. Rest all looks good.

Comment: I missed one thing instead of `invoke('text')`, you can directly use the `should('have.text')` assertion as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variation of your test, using the element passed down after `.type()`.

```js
cy.get('#comments').type('TEST')
  .then($comments => {
    cy.get('#comments-size')
      .should('have.text', `*${$comments.text().length}/4000 Characters Used`)
  })
```

Since you are using `.type()` I am surprised to see `.text()` work.

Normally you use `.type()` on an `<input>` which requires `.val()` to fetch the typed-in text.